# How to use JMRTD in Android Studio where build system is Gradle?

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm currently trying to use open source JMRTD in an Android project where it can read Machine Readable Travel Document (MRTD) standards. Based on what I read so far, gradle can support maven artifact and so I need to defined jmrtd as a dependency. It make me a little relieved.

Second, it is a must to use combo jmrtd + scuba in this project?
One of my friend suggest to me to use jmrtd + scuba ant file which floating around. But it not sound a good idea and solution to me. There also some discussion state that (**I forgot what are the link is), there are some issues with the dependency on Scuba and JMRTD where in maven repo produced by ant build system file actually contains duplicates of every class. And gradle will not allow it and will cause build failure.

So back to main question:
**How to use JMRTD in Android Studio where build system is Gradle?**  
And what is the element or library should I use together?
I am nowhere to find the implementation and tutorial of jrmtd in gradle.